Sum of two different self-adjoint extensions of a closed symmetric operator.
Let ${\cal H}=L^2([0,1])$. Consider the closed symmetric operator $A:D(A)\to {\cal H}$ defined by $Af=-f''$, where
$$ D(A)=\{f\in {\cal H}|f''\in {\cal H} \text{ (dist) }, f(0)=0, f'(0)=0, f'(1)=0\}. $$
$A$ is not self-adjoint, but it has self-adjoint extensions.
The operators $A_\alpha$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ with domain
$$D(A_\alpha)=\{f\in {\cal H}|f''\in {\cal H} \text{ (dist) }, f'(0)-\alpha f(0)=0, f'(1)=0\}. $$
and $A_\alpha f=-f''$ are self-adjoint extensions of $A$.
Can we define the sum $A_\text{sum}=A_0+A_1$? Is there a preferred or unique way to do this?
If so, does the Trotter product formula apply in some sense?
$$e^{-tA_{\text{sum}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(e^{-tA_0/n}e^{-t A_1/n}\right)^n$$
I would guess $A_\text{sum}=2A_{1/2}$ if this is the case, but I don't have a proof. The intersection $D(A_0)\cap D(A_1)$ equals $D(A)$, so the prerequisites for Trotter's result are not satisfied.
Note: $A_0$ describes the time derivative of the pressures in a 1D-reservoir with a with no-flow boundaries at 0 and 1 ("closed"), $A_1$ a reservoir with a no-flow boundary at $1$ and a constant pressure boundary Robin boundary condition at $0$ ("open"). This Trotter product (for finite $n$) represents the evolution of the system over an interval of length $2t$. Over this interval we alternate between "open" and "closed" $2n$-times, letting the system evolve for a time interval of length $t/n$ each time. $\alpha$ is like $f'(0)=\alpha f(0)$ is the rate at which we are depleting the reservoir. $1/\alpha$  can be seen as some sort of resistance. So, $1/2$ looks reasonable for a system that is open only half the time. (Still).
Edited: my initial note contained some inaccuracies.

I believe the form sum of $A_0$ and $A_1$ equals $2A_{1/2}$. If you are interested I will try to work out the details later.

@Steen82. Yes, I'm interested. That looks like a promising idea.

Outline (not a complete solution). I will discuss the form sum. Another possibly simpler method, still using forms, might be to use the Friedrichs extension, I think that would give a different sum operator.
Given the note at the end of the OP's question assume $0\leq \alpha.$
Write $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1 f\overline{g}$ for the inner product in $L^2([0,1])$ and $\|f\|=\langle f,f\rangle^{1/2}$ for the corresponding norm.
Integration by parts gives
$$
\langle A_{\alpha}f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 -f''\overline{g} = \alpha f(0)\overline{g(0)}+\int_0^1 f'\overline{g'}.
$$
In particular, $\langle A_{\alpha}f,g\rangle=\alpha|f(0)|^2+\|f'\|^2\geq0,$ so $A_{\alpha}$ is a positive self-adjoint operator. The corresponding form is
$$
b_{\alpha}(f,g)=\langle A_{\alpha}^{1/2}f,A_{\alpha}^{1/2}g\rangle= \alpha f(0)\overline{g(0)}+\int_0^1 f'\overline{g'},
$$
whose domain is $\mathrm{Dom}(b_{\alpha})=\mathrm{Dom}(A_{\alpha}^{1/2})\times \mathrm{Dom}(A_{\alpha}^{1/2}).$
Since $\mathrm{Dom}(A)\subset \mathrm{Dom}(A_0)\cap \mathrm{Dom}(A_1)$ and $\mathrm{Dom}(A_{\alpha}\subset\mathrm{Dom}(A_{\alpha}^{1/2})$ the intersection $\mathrm{Dom}(A_0^{1/2})\cap \mathrm{Dom}(A_1^{1/2})$ is dense in $L^2([0,1]).$ Hence, the form
$b(f,g)=b_0(f,g)+b_1(f,g),$ $f,g\in\mathrm{Dom}(A_0^{1/2})\cap \mathrm{Dom}(A_1^{1/2})$ determines a positive operator $A_0+A_1$ (the form sum) whose domain satisfies $\mathrm{Dom}(A_0+A_1)\subset\mathrm{Dom}((A_0+A_1)^{1/2})=\mathrm{Dom}(A_{0}^{1/2})\cap \mathrm{Dom}(A_{1}^{1/2})$. Since $b_0+b_1=2b_{1/2},$ it follows that $A_0+A_1=2A_{1/2}.$
I am leaving out many details and unfortunately do not have the time to fill in more at this time. The required theory of sesquilinear forms and operators can be found in the book "Intermediate Spectral Theory and Quantum Dynamics" by Oliveira (specifically sections 4.1, 4.2, and 9.3, a similar example is also discussed in these sections) and, if I recall correctly, the theory is also in the books by Reed and Simon (but I gave those away a few years ago).

Thanks. I still ,have my Reed and Simon books. I will check it out.
